# python, TensorFlow and machine learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm working on TensorFlow with machine learning.

I got stuck in **step1** and **step2**

**step1:**

```
X = X/255.0
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'

**step2:**

```
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=X.shape[1:])
```

> 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

**Edit 25/08-2019 13:44**

Step1: X=np.array(X)

Got new error in step2

Step2:

> Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: expected
>   ndim=4, found ndim=1. Full shape received: [None]

**Edit 25/08-2019 19:26**
my full code:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle
import numpy as np

X = pickle.load(open("x.pickle", "rb"))
y = pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb"))

X = np.array(X)

X = X/255.0
#x.shape=np.array([x])
#X = np.asarray(x).shape[1:]

print(X.shape)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
#model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=x.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=1, validation_split=0.1)
```

X.Shape = (24946,)

Comment: Try `X=np.array(X)` before step 1

Answer (score 0):

conv2d expects input tensor of shape [batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels](4 dimensional shape), check the shape of your X.